# How can I space out a vertical LinearLayout within a parent vertical LinearLayout so that it fills out the screen?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-view, spacing, android-layout-weight

I currently have the following layout:

[image]

The highlighted layout is a LinearLayout with three additional horizontal linearlayouts in it (one for each text+seekbar combination).

I would like the highlighted LinearLayout to expand and fill the space of the screen such that the "SAVE" button is at the bottom of the screen.

I have tried using `android:layout_weight` and assigning the same weight to each of the children of the highlighted layout but it does not seem to make a difference.

The following is my layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/add_mood_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/because_text"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@string/because" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/moodCommentEditText"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:hint="@string/add_a_comment_here" />

    </LinearLayout>

<!-- HIGHLIGHTED LAYOUT -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/happy_text"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                tools:text="Unhappy"
                android:layout_width="65sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1" />

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/happiness_seekbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:max="100"
                android:theme="@style/happinessSeekbarTheme" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/stress_text"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                android:layout_width="65sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="@string/stress" />

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/stress_seekbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:max="100"
                android:theme="@style/stressSeekbarTheme" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pain_text"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                android:layout_width="65sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="@string/pain" />

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/pain_seekbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:max="100"
                android:maxHeight="3dp"
                android:theme="@style/painSeekbarTheme" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try using RelativeLayout?

Comment: @damememan expected output will help to give a better answer

Comment: @Goran I want to avoid using RelativeLayout because as far as I know the only way to space things is using margins and padding, which can result in unpredictable behaviour across different screen sizes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the topmost `LinearLayout`'s `android:layout_height` to `match_parent` - it's currently set to `wrap_content`, which means that it will shrink to the smallest possible height that allows it to properly render its children.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/add_mood_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/because_text"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="@string/because" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/moodCommentEditText"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:hint="@string/add_a_comment_here" />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- HIGHLIGHTED LAYOUT -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/happy_text"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
            tools:text="Unhappy"
            android:layout_width="65sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/happiness_seekbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="100"
            android:theme="@style/happinessSeekbarTheme" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stress_text"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
            android:layout_width="65sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@string/stress" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/stress_seekbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="100"
            android:theme="@style/stressSeekbarTheme" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pain_text"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
            android:layout_width="65sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@string/pain" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/pain_seekbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="100"
            android:maxHeight="3dp"
            android:theme="@style/painSeekbarTheme" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/saveButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:text="@string/save"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue with a helper SPACE view.

You add an empty View with a weight - so that it will force the following view in the LinearLayout to be positioned at the end.

**Note:** Android has a special view for that purpose [Space](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space.html), but it only got in in API Level 14.

Like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/add_mood_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" <!-- Also changed this -->
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/because_text"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="@string/because" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/moodCommentEditText"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:hint="@string/add_a_comment_here" />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- HIGHLIGHTED LAYOUT -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/happy_text"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
            tools:text="Unhappy"
            android:layout_width="65sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/happiness_seekbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="100"
            android:theme="@style/happinessSeekbarTheme" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stress_text"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
            android:layout_width="65sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@string/stress" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/stress_seekbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="100"
            android:theme="@style/stressSeekbarTheme" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pain_text"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
            android:layout_width="65sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@string/pain" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/pain_seekbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="100"
            android:maxHeight="3dp"
            android:theme="@style/painSeekbarTheme" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<!-- Space View: Add this view here for white space -->
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/saveButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:text="@string/save"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```